# adding an image on java frame

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, embedded-resource

I have this problem in practice, the frame does not display the image I have in the folder image, someone can tell me why? i add the hierarchy of the project [image]

```
package frame;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Frame {
  Frame() {
    final JFrame login = new JFrame();
    login.setTitle("Title");
    login.setLayout(null);
    login.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Images/images.png")));
    login.setVisible(true);
    login.setSize(500, 400);
    login.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Frame();
}

}
```

Comment: By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Comment: You should also schedule your Frame() constructor to run on the EDT by using the invokeLater method of the Swing Utilities - this will ensure the GUI won't seize up when a background process is started, like logging in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid setLayout (null), if you do not have sound reason for it. Remove the below code. Image will get displayed.

If you still have to use a null layout, you have to set the width and height of the component, along with its its x and y position.

```
   login.setLayout(null);
```

Comment: +1, but we've already gone down this route with this OP (multiple times).  You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make them drink.

Answer (score 1):

For getting resources from project use `URL` instead of `String` path. For example:

```
URL resource = Frame.class.getResource("/Images/images.png");
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(resource);
JLabel lbl = new JLabel(icon);
```

Also read [that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/retrievingResources.html).

Also don't use null `LayoutManager`, in that case you need to specify bounds of component with help of `setBounds()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a package for resources. Instead, create a non-source folder called "images", and move it there.

After that, use that path "images/images.png"

Comment: inside src or outside?

Comment: @MaximShoustin in you opinion?